# Use final price in addFieldToFilter

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection, collection-filtering, special-price

I am using this code to filter products by min and max price

**updated code**

```
     $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
            ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'visibility', 'eq'=>"4")));
     }
        if(sizeof($years)>0){
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('year', array('in' => $years));
        }
        if(!empty($minprice) && !empty($maxprice)){
                $collection->addFieldToFilter('price',array('gteq'=>$minprice))
                           ->addFieldToFilter('price',array('lteq'=>$maxprice));
        }
```

But if products have special price it  works wrong. I need to use final price here. How can I do this?

---

**Answer** that I found while exploring magento native layered navigation

```
$collection->addFinalPrice();
$select = $collection->getSelect();
$select->where('price_index.final_price >= ' . $minprice);
$select->where('price_index.final_price < ' . $maxprice);
```

Answer (score 6):

Well the field for "final price" has code `final_price` in Magento Eav product table.

First you have to add final price to the collection as below:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addFinalPrice();
```

Then you can filter the collection by `final_price` as below:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('final_price',array('gteq'=>$minprice))
           ->addFieldToFilter('final_price',array('lteq'=>$maxprice));
```

Comment: I am getting an error Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816. In this line there is this code: $attrInstance = $this->getAttribute($attribute); $attrBackendStatic  = $attrInstance->getBackend()->isStatic();

Comment: Have you upgraded Magento recently to version ce 1.9 ? Which subversion ? 1.9.2.2 ?

Comment: version is 1.9.1.1

Comment: @Jeremy It seems one of your attributes you're passing in the collection for filtering is broken, can you update your question to include the whole collection query you are using ?

Comment: code was updated

Comment: Most likely there is no field like `year` in your current setup or that field is broken leading to fatal error. Please check that field, let me know if any issue in that field.

Comment: I commented part with year field but error has not disappeared

Comment: Same problem for me. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to add price filters is using the existing methods that take advantage of the price index.

#### Example:

```
// join the price index
$collection->addFinalPrice();

// add filters
$collection->addPriceDataFieldFilter('%s <= %s', ['final_price', $minPrice]);
$collection->addPriceDataFieldFilter('%s >= %s', ['final_price', $maxPrice]);
```

Alternatively, look at the layered navigation to see how price filters are implemented there.

Comment: Would this be possible to add "easily" here? https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts (I'd like to help - but can assume adding it to the grid + adding the frontend filters would already come a long way). thx Sean

Comment: This works perfectly for frontend, but how can I use that price filter in backend